# Async Web service call in Angular 2

Tags: json, node.js, web-services, angular

I have a Function that makes a call to the web service. The web service is returning the json values correctly but it is not displayed in the console (this.apartments)

```
Search(event){
  console.log('Search Enter Submitted' + event.target.value);
  this.apartmentService.searchApt(event.target.value).subscribe(res => this.apartments = res);
  console.log(this.apartments); 
}
```

I know that this is an async call. How can I chain it to get the value in this.apartments ?

Comment: Just move the log into the callback.

Comment: can you give more details please

Comment: Well you know it's an async call, and you've written a callback for it, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want the values displayed in the console (this.apartments). It is null at first, and always returning the previous value. not the current value.

Comment: So **put that log into the callback**, where you actually have that value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
this.apartmentService
    .searchApt2(event.target.value)
    .subscribe(res => {this.apartments = res console.log(this.apartments)});
```

Comment: Mark this as `answered`. It is ok to self answer.